# Why python class no __init__ when call a method?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I'm building a service to consume Kafka with python. For do that, I trying to create a more friendly approach using decorators to subscribe in topics.

```py
class MyController:
    def __init__(self, my_service: MyService):
        self.my_service = my_service()

    @event_pattern("my-kafka-topic")
    def my_method(self, payload):
        self.service.some_method() #-> The problem in here
```

In my `decorators.py`

```py
_registry_patterns = []
def event_pattern(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        _registry_patterns.append(
            {
                "topic": args[0],
                "callback": func,
            }
        )
        return func
    return wrapper

class KafkaClient(KafkaBackend):
    def __init__(self, config: dict):
        super().__init__(config, _registry_patterns)

    @property
    def __name__(self):
        return "KafkaClient"
```

Printing the decorator `func`, `args` and `kwargs`

```
func: <function MyController.my_method at 0xffff8a3c9a60>
args: ('my-kafka-topic',)
kwargs: {}
```

So, in KafkaBackend I've:

```py
class KafkaBackend(AbstractBackend):
    def __init__(self, config: dict, patterns: list):
        self.config = config
        self.topics = [p["topic"] for p in patterns]
        self._handlers = {p["topic"]: p["callback"] for p in patterns}

    def listen(self):
        self.consumer = Consumer(self.config)
        self.consumer.subscribe(self.topics)
        logger.debug(f"Subscribed to topics (KafkaBackend): {self.topics}")
        logger.debug(f"Handlers (KafkaBackend): {self._handlers}")

        while True:
            msg = self.consumer.poll(0.5)
            if msg is None:
                continue
            if msg.error():
                logger.info(f"Error: {msg.error()}")
                continue
            if msg:
               print("instance", self._handlers[msg.topic()])
               print("method_executed", self._handlers[msg.topic()](msg))
```

```
instance <function MyController.my_method at 0xffffa9b07a60>
....
TypeError: my_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload'
```

The error is raised because the `MyController` wasn't the `__init__` method called, right? I think, because the `my_method` receives the `self` a `payload` args and in this runtime, `self` wan't defined

It's a problem in dependency injection or I can resolve with any more complicated approach?

I can send a minimum repository to reproduce, if you guys need.

Comment: The problem that the error message relates to is that you have registered: `function MyController.my_method`. That is, a function, not a bound method. When do you make instances of `MyController`?

Comment: I just figured out that I don't create a instance of the `MyController` nowhere.